# Why $1/e^2$ of maximum intensity is used to calculate beam diameter?

Tags: optics, waves, laser

I was confused between FWHM and $1/e^2$ to find beam diameter of laser beam. Why $e^2$ and not $e $?
Which is more beneficial FWHM or $1/e^2$?

Answer (score 2):

For a gaussian beam, the electric field goes as:
$$ E \propto \exp \left ( -\frac{r^2}{w^2} \right ), $$
where $w$ is the waist, defined as the radius at which the field drops by a factor of $\mathrm{e}$.

What you actually observe on a camera, however, is the *intensity* $I \propto |E|^2$:
$$ I \propto \exp \left ( -\frac{2r^2}{w^2} \right ), $$
where $w$ is not the radius at which the *intensity* has dropped by a factor of $\mathrm{e}^2$.